# Do generalizations of the identity $\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k} (\zeta(n) -1) = 1 $ exist?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

On p. 263 of Borwein's [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700003368) entitled “Computational Strategies for the Riemann zeta function”, the following identity is stated: $$\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k} (\zeta(n) -1) =1 . \qquad \qquad (*)$$It is valid for all nonnegative integer $k$.

Can the identity be generalised and/or are there variations of it involving binomial sums which are also valid for infinitely many nonnegative lower bounds $k$?

I suppose one can rewrite the formulas of Landau: $$ \frac{1}{s-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+n-1}{n-1} \frac{\zeta(s+n)-1}{n} $$ and Ramaswami: $$ (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{s+n-1}{n} \zeta(s+n)$$ in a manner that is similar to $(*)$, but I'm looking for both more and more general examples of such sums. Preferably, all sums in the collection amount to the same constant and involve binomial coefficients.

Comment: These later identities are wrong. The first sum should be be $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+s-1}{n-1} \frac{(\zeta(s+n)-1)}{n}$$. And the second identity isn't converging. That may be $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{s+n-1}{n}(\zeta(s+n)-1)$$.

Comment: @AlapanDas Hmm, these identities were retrieved from p. 286 of Borwein's paper. So if they're wrong, you've found an error in a peer-reviewed article. Do you have sources for your expressions?

Comment: These identities can be proved by the identity $\zeta(n)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x-1} dx$. Also, I have checked these identities in Wolfram alpha.

Comment: In my first comment, I have made a small error in the second identity. If we take $n$ from $1$, then the value is $1$, if the limit is from $n=0$, then the value will be $\zeta(s)$.