# Rational zeta series and differential-difference equations

Tags: analytic-number-theory, differential-equations, sequences-and-series, difference-equations, umbral-calculus

In an earlier [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372099/do-generalizations-of-the-identity-sum-n-k2-infty-binomn-1k-zeta),  I mentioned I was looking for generalizations of $$\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k} (\zeta(n) -1) =1. \qquad \qquad (1) $$
A variation of the above identity arises by [considering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Taylor_series) the Taylor series of the Hurwitz zeta function. As $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \zeta(s,q) = -s \zeta(s+1,q), \qquad \qquad (2)$$ we obtain \begin{align}\zeta(s,x+y) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{k}}{k!} \frac{\partial^{k}}{\partial x^{k}} \zeta(s,x) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} (-y)^{k} \zeta(s+k,x). \qquad \qquad(3) \end{align}
We could differentiate functions that are similar to the one from $(2)$ and see what happens. For instance, define $$ \zeta_{2}(s,s;a) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1+a)^{s}} \sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(m+a)^{s}} . \qquad \qquad (4)$$ This is a generalization of the Multiple Zeta [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) where we set $s_{1} = s_{2} = s$. Then:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \zeta_{2}(s,s;a) = -s(\zeta_{2}(s+1,s;a) + \zeta_{2}(s,s+1;a) ) . \qquad \qquad (5)$$
Here we see the [shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_sequence) that are similar to the one found in $(2)$. We could do something like this for a generalization of the [Mordell-Tornheim](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6fb8/e296396043fba4a46ab561679a2c99cf8e43.pdf) zeta function as well.

**Question**

Have equations like $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} f(s,s;a) = -s(f(s+1,s;a) + f(s,s+1;a) ) $$ been studied before, from the perspective of differential-difference equations? Or have they perhaps been considered in the umbral calculus?